# Images of Functions and their Preimages

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $f: A \to B$ and suppose $C ⊆ A$ and $D ⊆ B$

Prove or give a counterexample:

a) $f(C) ⊆ D \iff C ⊆ f^{-1}(D)$. This is true correct?

b) If $f$ is injective then $f^{-1}(f(C)) = C$

This is simple, that the $\operatorname{id}_A(C) = C$ since it is injective right?

c) If $f$ is surjective, then $f[f^{-1}(D)]=D$

Same as $B$ right ?

d) Prove $C ⊆ f[f^{-1}(C)]$

e) Prove $f[f^{-1}(C)] ⊆ D$ Same as $B$ right ?

Comment: a) is not necessarily correct, unless $f$ is surjective/bijective.

Comment: @Vectk I was thinking about something else - a moment of weakness! I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You may find this useful. You should take the time to prove it to yourself rigorously.

**Theorem**: For any function $A\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} B$, the following hold:

(1) $f$ is injective $\iff f^{-1}f=\operatorname{Id}_A \iff f^{-1}f(S)\subset S$ for all $S\subset A$

(2) $f$ is surjective $\iff ff^{-1}=\operatorname{Id}_B \iff T\subset ff^{-1}(T)$ for all $T\subset B$

Comment: Yes so f^−1fC ⊂ C, how do i show it equals it?

Comment: The containments in the other directions are true for every function. Surely you can show that? Start with $c\in C$...

Comment: Recall that $f^{-1}(Y)=\{a\in A:f(a)\in Y\}$. Put $Y=f(C)$ and let $c\in C$. Then surely $c\in f^{-1}(Y)$ since $f(c)\in Y= f(C)$--that is, $c\in f^{-1}f(C)$. Since $c$ was an arbitrary element of $C$, it must be the case that every element of $C$ lies in $f^{-1}f(C)$, so $\boxed{C\subset f^{-1}f(C)}$ as desired.